# Javascript Removing Event Listener

Tags: javascript

I have a photo viewer html page where users can view images in a local folder as a slideshow. I have a checkbox where users can select the image they are viewing for later actions. Users can select an image, go to the next image, select that one as well, etc. When I load a new image, I have a variable `img_path` that is passed to the event listener of the checkbox.

My problem is that when I load a new image, the old event listener with the old `img_path` is not removed and instead every event listener remains.

For example, when I select and then deselect the first image in the slideshow everything is fine and the console output is

```
Selecting images/00001.jpg
Deselecting images/00001.jpg
```

But when I go to the second image and then select and deselect the output is

```
Selecting images/00001.jpg
Selecting images/00002.jpg
Deselecting images/00001.jpg
Deselecting images/00002.jpg
```

This is my code:

```js
// This is called every time the user hits the next button
function set_slide(img_id, select_box) {

    ...

    let img_path = "images/" + img_id + ".jpg"

    function select_event() {
        if(select_box.checked) {
            console.log("Selecting " + img_path)
            select_img(img_path);
        }
        else {
            console.log("Deselecting " + img_path)
            deselect_img(img_path);
        }
    }

    select_box.removeEventListener("click", select_event, false);
    select_box.addEventListener("click", select_event, false);
}
```

Where `select_box` comes from:

```js
// This only happens once when the slideshow page is created
let select_box = document.createElement('input');
select_box.type = "checkbox"
```

I am trying to use `removeEventListener` to remove the old event listener with the old `img_path` variable, but I must be doing it wrong.

Comment: The function `select_event` that you try to remove **is not** the function `select_event` that  you have added with the first call. It's a new one. For this case, it might be the simplest to use `select_box.onclick`

Comment: @Thomas Yes of course I should have realized that. Your solution worked perfectly thank you!